# row is too big: size 8480, maximum size 8160

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Getting below exception while uploading CSV file into a table.
 **ERROR** :row is too big: size 8480, maximum size 8160
Table having 1000 columns.
 Can anyone  give me a suggestion How to identify  on which column  its violating exception.

Thanks

Comment: Without at least some information about the table's definition that's hard to answer. However, a table with 1000 columns is more often than not in need of some thorough refactoring/normalization.

Comment: It's very difficult to publish those many columns information..but I went through some articles got information because of  column storage types..here I don't know which column need to change storage type to plain .